# this in c++. how does it work?

Tags: c++, this

I have a question about my C++ homework. I am just confused about *this.

The code below is what I have.

My question is why the condition in the if statement in the = operator is true?

```
#include <cstring>
class abc {
      char p[9];
      int inc;
   public:
      abc( ) { inc = 8; strcpy(p, "10010101"); }
      ~abc( );
      abc& operator=(const abc &);

};

abc::~abc( ) {

}
abc& abc::operator=(const abc &c) {
   if(this != &c) { //my question is why this condition is true?
      inc = c.inc - 2;
      for(int i=0; i<inc; i++) {
     p[i] = c.p[i] + 2;
      }
   }
   return *this;
}

int main( ) {
   abc x, y;
   x = y;
   return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you don't want to make a copy if you are assigning to yourself, that is the reason for the `if` condition, `*this` returns self instance. It is true because you are trying to assign `y to x` and as they are both different instances you then make a `copy` of `y to x`.

Comment: Ok. I dont' understand how come the two objects x and y are not equal to make the if statement's condition true?

Comment: You are comparing addresses in the if condition, not the values, so their addresses will be different.

Comment: so that means. "this" stands for x. and the == doesn't mean that the values of x and y are equal, right?

Comment: @ahmadhussain it doesn't compare value but address!

Comment: @ahmadhussain `this` means the `address of x` and because you are comparing `this` with `&c` the addresses are different so they are different instances of `abc` so copy the values.

Answer (score 1):

`*this == &c` only in case of the left operand of operator= is the same as the right operand.
In case of `x = y` ==> `*this != &c`.
In case of `x = x` ==> `*this == &c` because both are the same.
It is commonly use because you don't need a copy if you assign to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
if(this != &c) { //my question is why this condition is true?
```

is used to detect self-assignment.  If you have an object of type `abc` and write

```
abc a;
a = a;
```

Then you will call `operator =` on `a`, passing itself as a parameter.  Many implementations of the assignment operator break in this case, because in cleaning up the object in preparation for the copy, the argument to `operator =` (in this case, `a` itself) will also be cleaned up.  It can easily lead to crashes.  Consequently, many implementations of `operator =` begin with a test that the argument and the receiver object aren't the same object.  The above test does this by seeing if the `this` pointer (the receiver) and the address of the argument (`&c`) are the same.  If so, the objects are the same and the assignment shouldn't be done.  Otherwise, the objects aren't the same and the assignment should be done.

As for returning `*this`, since `this` is a pointer to the receiver object, `*this` is the receiver object itself.  Returning `*this` by reference means that you can write things like

```
(a = b) = c;
```

Which, while silly, is supposed to be legal C++.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `if`statement  evaluates to `true` because you are not assigning an object instance to itself, thus satisfying the `!=` operator.  You have two separate objects, `x` and `y`. They have their own unique `this` values.  Had you said `x = x` instead in `main()`, then the `!=` operator in the `if` statement would evaluate to `false` instead because the two values would match.

Answer (score 0):

It is comparing the address of the object passed to the class with address object that is pointed by `this` . If the addresses are the same then you have passed the object itself which we don't want to operate upon. With `*this` you are in fact passing the pointer reference in the operator.